# Magento: Depending on the payment method, the invoice email blocks are either taken from design/frontend/base or /frontend/default

Tags: php, magento, paypal

The title pretty much sums up my question.

If I make a payment through paypal, the templates for the invoice email is taken from design/frontend/base..., but if I make a payment with Prepayment, and generate the invoice from admin, the templates for the invoice email are taken from base.

Any ideas why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is because paying by Paypal is different to paying with 'Prepayment' and the invoice template that is used is a different one.

With any email template the theme folders are checked first, if the .html template is not found then the default/base folder is checked. You may need to copy/synchronise the .html files used for email templates between your base and theme folders to fix this problem.

Comment: They are most definitely not out of sync because the .phtml template file included fron /base has the exact same path / name as the one in my theme, which gets loaded when paying with paypal.

Comment: Can you clarify pre-payment method? Is that this: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Phoenix/extension/304/bank-prepayment-vorkasse-

Comment: Yes, that's the one. Thanks so much for taking the time to help me. The template that should be overriden is /design/frontend/base/default/templates/email/order/items/invoice/default.phtml

Comment: It is a problem with the module that you can contact the developer to fix. In the interim you can make a soft link (ln -s) from the one file to the other. If you want to fix it properly for yourself then you can  trawl through the module's files that can be found in the /downloader folder (search for Phoenix). I am sure the developer will be glad to have a fix for the bug rather than just a bug report. But, to get your store on the road the soft link option will take you less time.

Comment: Where did you found that this is a bug? Also, I can't find any /downloader in my Phoenix folder

Comment: downloader/pearlib/download/BankPayment-x.x.x/Phoenix in your folder root has the original module files. It is a bug since it affect only this payment type.